# cv2_imshow in Google Colab causes images to be stacked on top of each other instead of displaying them in the same feed

Tags: python, user-interface, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Im not sure if this is a limitation of Colab, Im trying to implement a pong game with opencv, Im using modified code from a tutorial https://github.com/darthdaenerys/Pong-Game/blob/master/game.py

My code modifications are below

After replacing cv2.show with cv2_show as requested by Colab, it seems to produce infinite frames as images and stacks them on top of each other instead of producing a moving video in the same space.

Is it possible to display the images in the same space as a game would, or is that impossible with Colaband I need to install jupyter to get it to work?

If it is possible, please post recommended code change

if it is not possible, is there at least a way to remove the previous image before showing the next one so its not stacking images on top of each other

Thanks

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

# parameters
width=1280
height=720
paddlewidth=150
paddleheight=20
paddlecolor=(75, 153, 242)
lives=3
deltax=10
deltay=-10
xpos=640
ypos=400
level=1
ball=True
ballradius=8
highscore=0
bgcolor=(30,79,24)
scorecolor=(149, 129,252)

prevval=683
myscore=0

while True:
    background=np.zeros([720,1366,3],dtype=np.uint8)
    background[:,:]=bgcolor
    val = random.randint(0, 1000)
    if val==0:
        val=prevval
    else:
        prevval=val
    cv2.rectangle(background,(1366-(val-paddlewidth//2),720-paddleheight),(1366-(val+paddlewidth//2),720),paddlecolor,-1)
    paddlerightcorner=(1366-(val-paddlewidth//2),720-paddleheight)
    paddleleftcorner=(1366-(val+paddlewidth//2),720-paddleheight)
    if ball==True:
        cv2.circle(background,(xpos,ypos),ballradius,(255,255,255),-1)
        xpos+=deltax
        ypos+=deltay
    if xpos>=1360 or xpos<=5:
        deltax=-deltax
    if ypos<=10:
        deltay=-deltay
    if xpos<=paddlerightcorner[0] and xpos>=paddleleftcorner[0]:
        if ypos>=695 and ypos<=710:
            deltay=-deltay
            myscore+=1
            if myscore%5==0 and myscore>=5:
                level+=1
                if deltax<0:
                    deltax-=2
                else:
                    deltax+=2
                if deltay<0:
                    deltay-=1
                else:
                    deltay+=1
    cv2.putText(background,'Lives: '+str(lives),(1200,35),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,2,scorecolor,2)
    cv2.putText(background,'Level: '+str(level),(1200,68),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,2,scorecolor,2)
    cv2.putText(background,'Score: '+str(myscore),(1200,101),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,2,scorecolor,2)
    if ypos>=720:
        lives-=1
        temp=cv2.blur(background,(15,15))
        cv2.putText(temp,'You Lost a Life !',(300,360),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX,3,(185,89,200),3,1)
        cv2_imshow(temp)
        cv2.waitKey(2000)
        xpos=640
        ypos=400
        if deltay>0:
            deltay=-deltay
    if lives==0:
        ball=False
        deltax=10
        deltay=-10
        level=0
        background=cv2.blur(background,(20,20))
        cv2.waitKey(1000)
        for i in range(0,720,10):
            background[i:i+10,:]=(24,34,255)
            cv2_imshow(background)
            cv2.waitKey(10)
        cv2.putText(background,'GAME OVER',(400,360),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX,3,(0,255,255),2)
        cv2.putText(background,'Your Score: '+str(myscore),(420,420),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,2,(0,255,35),2)
        if myscore>highscore:
            highscore=myscore
        cv2.putText(background,'HIGH SCORE: '+str(highscore),(420,480),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,2,(0,255,56),2)
        cv2.putText(background,'Press q twice to exit or game restarts in 5 seconds',(300,550),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX,1,(255,0,0),2)
        cv2_imshow(background)
        cv2.waitKey(5000)
        ball=True
        myscore=0
        lives=3
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff==ord('q'):
        break
    cv2_imshow(background)
```

Comment: I suspect that in this case you can stick with the old tech that Google Colab presently uses. No need to install modern Jupyter because I don't think the output clearing has changed significantly since this time. Have you tried using`clear_output(wait=True)` between each iteration, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73064306/8508004)?

Comment: mistag. it's [tag:google-colab], with a single L, not LL. the site should have asked you whether you really want to create a new tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear output in jupyter notebook cell after each for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69964261/how-to-clear-output-in-jupyter-notebook-cell-after-each-for-loop)

Comment: jupyter notebooks (colab) are not for "video" displays.

Answer (score 0):

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML, clear_output

clear_output(wait=True)
```